# How to enforce metadata in document information panel in SP2010

Tags: document-library, content-type, file-upload, document-info-panel

My document library supports several custom content types. When "Add new document" is clicked, the Browse dialog for uploading the file is followed by the Document Information Panel which is properly customized for whichever Content Type is chosen.

All is well except for the case of a user dismissing the DIP dialog by clicking Cancel.

The library has already stored the uploaded document but the metadata enforcement has been subverted by the user simply clicking Cancel. All content types have at least one required property which involves a choice from a Managed Metadata term store (there is no default term for this; would that tend to make this property "optional"??).

Is there a way to enforce the good intentions of the metadata designer somehow? Perhaps deleting the document if the metadata is not supplied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that by default uploaded files remain checked out until all required metadata fields have been provided. The user cannot check the document in unless they fill in the fields. As long as the document is checked out, only the user who uploaded it will be able to see it.

Scenario: Document Library with two content types, one is the default document, one is a custom content type with required metadata. I can upload a default document, and since it has no required metadata, the file will be checked in automatically.

If I upload a document with the custom content type, it will remain checked out to me until I have provided all then mandatory metadata fields. Any attempt to check in the document, or to edit the document with Word and then saving it back to the library will result in prompts to provide the missing data.

So, since nobody but the uploading user can see the checked out document, there is no need to delete it when metadata is missing. Nobody will see it, anyway, and the author will be prompted to supply the missing data before others can see it.

Comment: Thank you. I learned that the key is marking the library as requiring Versioning. Once that is done, then all the operations you describe above serve to keep the document without metadata "isolated" as you say, until the uploading user supplies the required metadata and checks in the document.